# Relationship between the Lebesgue measure of the largest open and closed set contained in a subset of R

Tags: general-topology, lebesgue-measure

Given an arbitrary set $E \subseteq R$

What is the relationship between the largest open and closed set contained in $E$?

> If $O$ is the largest open set contained in $E$ and $C$ the largest closed set contained in $E$
>
> IS $O \subset C$ or $C \subset O$?
>
> More importantly, Is $\lambda(C) = \lambda(O)$?

where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure!

Comment: A fat Cantor set is closed, has positive measure, and contains no non-empty open set.

Comment: What is the largest closed set contained in $(0,1)$?

Comment: The class of closed subsets of $E$ may not contain maximal elements. In fact, if $E$ is not closed, it hardly ever does.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X\subseteq \Bbb R$ be a measurable set; then for each $\epsilon \geq\,0$ there exist an open set $A$ and a closed set $C$ such that $C\subseteq X \subseteq A $ and $$L^n ( A\setminus C )\leq \epsilon . $$

So that the outer set is the open one while inside $X $ there's the closed set.

You can find this property on wikipedia, under the 9th property of the Lebesgue measure: [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure#Properties)

Comment: Yes I know. but am interested in both open sets and closed set contained in $X$